# How to edit a JSON file using shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, zsh, json

I am building a shell script that uses a JSON file.

```json
{
  "property1": true,
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "APP1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "APP2"
    }
  ],
  "property2": false
}
```

I need to use shell script to read the `name` from the `list` and remove its parent object from list. Basically I need to remove the object with name `APP1` from the `list` using shell. Editing JSON structure is not an option.

Comment: Look into the `jq` tool. It's purpose is parsing JSON. The usual UNIX text processing tools are not suitable for context-free languages like JSON.

Comment: What do you (Sidharth) mean by "Editing JSON structure is not an option"?

Comment: use python - it's a scripting language that you can write shell scripts with: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` - it has a json module with which you can load a json file into a dictionary object, manipulate it, then save it back to a file

Answer (score 30):

Using the del function in [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq 'del(.list[] | select(.name=="APP1"))'
```

If you wanted to pass the app name as a shell variable to jq you can use the [`--arg`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) option:

```
jq --arg name "$name" 'del(.list[] | select(.name==$name))'
```

Answer (score 4):

I would write the script using Python, which has JSON read/write functions built-in.

Given a file, `myfile.json`, containing the JSON object in the OP:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python  # Use the Python interpreter
from json import load, dump  # Import the JSON file read and write functions
with open("myfile.json", "r") as file_object:  # Open the JSON file for reading
    json_data = load(file_object)  # Load the data into a dictionary

new_list = [item for item in json_data["list"] if item["name"] != "APP1"]  # Make a new list without the item that should be removed
json_data["list"] = new_list  # Update the dictionary with the new list

with open("myfile.json", "w") as file_object:  # Open the JSON file for writing and truncate it
    dump(json_data, file_object)  # Write the file back to disk
```

Comment: You need to rewind `file_object` before writing, and truncate it after.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while iterating over it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: @Barmar good points, thanks, will fix..

Comment: @Barmar hopefully that's better now :-)

Comment: thanks, anonymous editor, i didn't know you could specify the language after the ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with [zq](https://zed.brimdata.io/docs/commands/zq/).

```
zq -f json '{...this, list: (over list | name != "APP1")}' input.json
```

zq is a command line tool for wrangling data. It uses the [Zed language](https://zed.brimdata.io/docs/language/overview/) to manipulate streams of values.

Answer (score 0):

[As shown by James Kerr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704917/116858) [and also by Aaron F](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/649688/116858), but using `jq` rather than `zq` or Python.  The operation sets the `.list` array to the elements of the original array that don't have `.name` equal to `APP1`.

```bash
$ jq '.list |= map(select(.name != "APP1"))' file
{
  "property1": true,
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "APP2"
    }
  ],
  "property2": false
}
```